# Chrome Debugger Date value

Tags: debugging, google-chrome, date

I am facing a strange problem. I worked with chrome debugger for hours and everything worked fine. Now it is nomore working correctly.

I have a date variable and expect the value to shown like:
end_date: Mon Nov 01 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0200 {}

But instead it shows only "Date" as value. I can perform any functions on it like .getDate() etc. but the value is not shown by default. Even when I put this into the console:

new Date()

I get this response:
Date

Have I turned something on which hides the value of a Date object?

Cheers